# Please explain the top part of this code, specifically the replaceAt part

Tags: javascript

In the following code, I kind of understand the bottom part, but I have never seen `replaceAt`.  I've only seen `replace` and `charAt`. So what is `replaceAt`?

Also, I have an issue with the `this` part, in understanding what `this` is actually capturing.

```
String.prototype.replaceAt = function(index, character) {
  return this.substr(0, index) + character + this.substr(index+character.length);
};


function titleCase(str) {
  var newTitle = str.split(' ');
  var updatedTitle = [];
  for (var st in newTitle) {
    updatedTitle[st] = newTitle[st].toLowerCase().replaceAt(0, newTitle[st].charAt(0).toUpperCase());
  }
  return updatedTitle.join(' ');
}
```

Comment: Studying [Inheritance and the Prototype Chain on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) might help explain why you have not have seen `replaceAt` before. [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is a special keyword for JavaScript functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funcion name `replaceAt`is a custom name, you can name it as you like, such as `myReplaceAt`

When making `String.prototype` functions, `this` inside function is the applied string, such as this example:

```
var myString = "test"
myString.myReplaceAt(...
```

Value of the `myString` is `this` inside `myReplaceAt`

Comment: I thought ‘.this’ could only be used in objects?

Answer (score 0):

String.prototype.replaceAt string method

allows you to replace a strings char at a specific index

```
String.prototype.replaceAt=function(index, char) {return this.substr(0, index) + char + this.substr(index+char.length);}
```